# activerecord class from custom sql query

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Is it possible to create an activerecord class from a custom sql query or view ?
It doesn't need to be editable.
example:

```
class c
  select a.*, b.* from a, b where a.code = b.code
end
```

This example is a join where all the fields from both tables are resent, the one to one joins in activerecord only present fields from one table, the others are accessible through a.bs.fieldname.
I would like them aal to be fields on the same level, thus in one class.

so that a.code, a.name and b.code, b.extra can be accessed as c.code, c.name, c.extra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveRecord will works with your views as with tables. So, firstly create custom view for your things

```
CREATE VIEW some_things AS (select a.*, b.* from a, b where a.code = b.code)
```

And then make ActiveRecord based class for accessing them (app/models/some_thing.rb)

```
class SomeThing < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

You can access to your things as like as any other AR objects

```
p SomeThing.where(code: 'xxx-yyy').order(:name).limit(10).all
```

Comment: The drawback of this approach is that most RDBMS systems don't allow an index on a view.  This means you're doing a linear scan to find the record you want.

Comment: You always can create indexes on source tables for increasing VIEW performance. So, in this case you can create 2 indexes: `a(code)` and `b(code)`. It will be good idea to add index by `a(name)` field.